# Prove $(F/R) \otimes_R (F/R)=0$ for $R$ an integral domain and $F$ its field of fractions

Tags: abstract-algebra, modules, tensor-products, integral-domain

> Suppose $R$ is an integral domain and $F=\mathrm{Frac}(R)$ is considered as an $R$-module. I want to prove that
>   $$(F/R) \otimes_R (F/R)=0.$$

My attempt:

I first considered the exact sequence
$$R \rightarrow F \rightarrow F/R \rightarrow 0$$
and from this I obtained the exact sequence
$$F/R \otimes_R R \overset{f}{\rightarrow} F/R \otimes_R F \overset{g}{\rightarrow} F/R \otimes_R F/R \rightarrow 0$$
If I can show that Im$f= F/R\otimes_R F$ then since Im$f=\ker g$
$$(F/R) \otimes_R (F/R)=0$$
but $F/R\otimes_R R \cong F/R$. This implies I need to show that
$$F/R \cong F/R\otimes_R F$$
I'm not quite sure if they are really isomorphic to each other.

---

Complete the proof:
Consider the map $\left(\frac{b}{a}+R \right) \otimes \frac{b'}{a'} \mapsto \frac{b}{a}+R$ for $a, a', b, b' \in R$. It is clearly surjective and $R$-linear. Now for $a'', b'' \in R$, we have
$$\left(\frac{b}{a}+R \right) \otimes \frac{b'}{a'}=a\left(\frac{b}{a}+R \right) \otimes \frac{b'}{aa'}=0\otimes \frac{b'}{aa'}=0=0\otimes \frac{b''}{aa''}=a\left(\frac{b}{a}+R \right) \otimes \frac{b''}{aa''}=\left(\frac{b}{a}+R \right) \otimes \frac{b''}{a'}$$
Hence the map is injective.

Comment: Do you know why, e.g., tensoring with $\mathbb{Q}$ kills all torsion?  Seems like the same proof would carry over here.

Comment: @ Randall I haven't heard about it yet. Could you explain about it?

Comment: It's embedded in the answer below, actually.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is covered in Cartan and Eilenberg, Homological Algebra, Chapter VII, Proposition 1.8. The proof goes like this.

Let $a\otimes b$ be an element of your tensor product. $F/R$ is a torsion $R$-module so there is a nonzero $r \in R$ for which $rb=0.$ But $F/R$ is also a divisible $R$-module, that is, its elements are divisible by nonzero elements of $R$. Hence, there is  an element $a'$ of $F/R$ such that $a=ra'.$ So, $a\otimes b = (ra')\otimes b = a' \otimes rb = a' \otimes 0 = 0.$ Hence, your tensor product is $0$.

Comment: Thanks, this is a neat way to prove it. I complete the proof using the similar logic. Does it look good?

Comment: @Andrew - I think you want to look at your map from the tensor product into $F/R.$ As you have it, it seems $b'/a'$ is irrelevant. Try multiplying the coset by $b'/a'.$ It's late here so I may be missing something. Anyway, I don't think that $F/R$ is isomorphic to $F/R \otimes_R F.$ Note that $a((b/a)+R)=b+R=0$ in $F/R$ since $b \in R.$ So, it seems that $F/R \otimes_RF=0.$ It might help if you work with the concrete situation $\mathbb{Q}/\mathbb{Z} \otimes \mathbb{Q}$ to get a handle on what's going on in general.

Comment: @Andrew - I made an edit to the answer. I mistakenly said nonzero integer instead of nonzero element of $R.$

Answer (score 1):

Let $x,y\in F $; then there exists $a,b\in R $ and $s,t\in R\setminus\{0\} $ such that $x=\frac as$ and $y=\frac bt $.
Then
\begin{align}
(x+R)\otimes (y+R)&=\left(\frac as+R\right)\otimes\left(\frac bt+R\right)\\
&=\left(\frac{at}{st}+R\right)\otimes\left(\frac bt+R\right)\\
&=\left(\frac{a}{st}+R\right)\otimes\left(\frac{bt}t+R\right)\\
&=\left(\frac{a}{st}+R\right)\otimes(b+R)\\
&=0
\end{align}